# Add Google ExoPlayer to Android studio gradle build

Tags: android-studio, gradle

If i have an Android app developed using Android Studio is it possible to link the ExoPlayer library (https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) straight from github using graddle?

It would be handy not to manually have to download the library and copy it into my project every time it's updated by the ExoPlayer team.

I have tried adding this to the `build.gradle` in my module.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://raw.github.com/google/ExoPlayer' }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer'
}
```

But i get an error about the module notation being invalid...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is now possible to add ExoPlayer as a jCenter dependency via gradle!

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.4.1'
}
```

Comment: jcenter() was missing ! Thanks.